# Event when element is changed

Tags: angular

Using Angular, I have built a table that interacts with a input used for searching. After pressing enter to trigger the search, the results are available almost immediately in the console. However, updating the table in the view can take several seconds. During this time, I'd like to display to the user that the content is loading but will need to hide the content when the HTML has finished updating.

Here is the HTML for the table:

```
<div class="table-responsive" *ngIf="searchData?.length" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
  <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let header of headers">{{header}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let record of searchData">
        <td>{{record.AccountNo}}</td>
        <td>{{record.CustomerTaxID_KB}}</td>
        <td>{{record.custName}}</td>
        <td><a href="{{record.FILE_NAME_KB}}">{{record.FILE_NAME_KB}}</a></td>
        <td>{{record.category}}</td>
        <td>{{record.IncidentComments}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

How can I listen for changes on the table for when it has completed updating?

Answer (score 0):

you can create one class for loading and add or remove class dynamically. here is the example i hope it helps you out

```
<div class="table-responsive" *ngIf="searchData?.length" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
  <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let header of headers">{{header}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let record of searchData; let i = index" [ngClass]="{ searchData.length === i ? '' : 'loadingClass'}">
         <!-- Hear you can see that we add class loadingClass when length is not equal to array length   -->
        <td>{{record.AccountNo}}</td>
        <td>{{record.CustomerTaxID_KB}}</td>
        <td>{{record.custName}}</td>
        <td><a href="{{record.FILE_NAME_KB}}">{{record.FILE_NAME_KB}}</a></td>
        <td>{{record.category}}</td>
        <td>{{record.IncidentComments}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
```

let me know if it is working or not